# AVAudio player always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I'm not sure why my `AVAudioPlayer` is always **nil**?

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@property (nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@synthesize audioPlayer;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Construct URL to sound file
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/background-music-aac.caf", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    // Create audio player object and initialize with URL to sound
    NSError *audioError = nil;
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:&audioError];
    if (audioPlayer == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error? %@", audioError);
        NSLog(@"AudioPlayer: %@", audioPlayer.description);
    }
```

I feel like I have this all set up right, but it doesn't work and I'm getting `nil`/`null` for the `audioPlayer`.

Comment: And what is the output for audioError and description?

Comment: It's `2016-05-28 19:01:19.850 Disk[7327:3298125] Error? Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "(null)"
2016-05-28 19:01:19.850 Disk[7327:3298125] AudioPlayer: (null)`

Comment: `2003334207 -- "Operation couldn't be completed"`. You need to make sure the path/url is correct. Either it can't find it, the file is corrupted, or the format of the file isn't valid. Try: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background-music-aac" ofType:@"caf"];` and print it. See if it exists.

Comment: So I swapped `NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/background-music-aac.caf", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];` for `NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background-music-aac" ofType:@"caf"];
` and got a crash when it hit that, saying: "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'"

Comment: I think it might be the .caf resource or something.  So your tip helped a lot.  I put an .mp3 in there instead and it worked, so that helps a lot knowing what the issue might be now! Very much appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .caf file was the problem, thanks to Brandon for the help